# Mapping kendo search query to elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch, kendo-ui

How can we map kendo UI query to elastic search query..
here is my standard Kendo query..

```
   filter:{  
   logic:and,
   filters:[  
      {  
         field:"firstname",
         operator:"eq",
         value:"john"
      },
      {  
         field:"lastname",
         operator:"eq",
         value:"doe"
      },
      {  
         field:"faiser",
         operator:"lte",
         value:"doe"
      },
      {  
         field:"faiser",
         operator:"lte",
         value:"doe"
      }
   ]
},
sort:{  
   field:"fullname",
   dir:"asc",

},
{  
   field:"fullname",
   dir:"desc",
}
```

Can we search this result from elastic search

Answer (score 0):

Both types of search are quite different and mapping them would be quite difficult. If you want to perform the search on the server I would rather recommend you to generate the endpoint url according to Elastic search syntax and consume it directly with the Kendo DataSource as it comes. If you need a client side filter for part of the data you could use the Kendo query syntax.